# Даже в хорошую погоду с залива дул резкий ветер

Tags: морфология

Какой частью речи является "даже" ?
Даже в хорошую погоду с залива дул резкий ветер.

ветер дул (когда?) -> "даже" в (какую?) хорошую (->прилагательное) погоду
в данном случае даже  вносит оттенок значения в предложение
выражает УСИЛЕННОЕ чувство и отношение говорящего
ПРАВ ЛИ Я ?

Comment: А что именно вы-то предлагаете? Да, "вносит оттенок". Для вас это что-то значит, но вы не знаете, что именно? Или вы в самом это утверждении, что-де вносит,  сомневаетесь?

Answer (score 1):

При решении подобных вопросов удобно использовать толковый словарь (например, на ГРАМОТЕ.РУ).

ДАЖЕ. I. частица. Употр. для выделения и усиления слова или словосочетания, к которому относится.

Comment: скажите, а может ли оно быть выражено другой частью речи ?

Comment: Может ли слово "даже" являться другой частью речи? Только в качестве союза: Ветер сильный, даже верхушки деревьев клонит. Или вы хотите заменить "даже" синонимом? Синоним трудно подобрать. Вот такой вариант: В хорошую погоду и то дул резкий ветер с залива..

Comment: Я не в восторге от вашего совета использовать словарь для решения подобных вопросов. Если человек не доверяет словарю, то переадресовывать его обратно - все равно, что возвращать на рассмотрение жалобы тому, на кого жалуются.